# innerHTML information

Tags: html

I have to re-make a part of my page. 
This is part of code that is making my link :

```
$downloadLinks .= '<li><a onclick="document.getElementById(\'last-crop-resize\').parentElement.style.backgroundColor=\'lightgreen\';document.getElementById(\'last-crop-resize\').innerHTML=this.href" target="_blank" href="'._CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL . '://' . file::getFileDomainAndPath($file->id, $file->serverId, true) . '/' . PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_NAME.'/images/scripts/resize_image.php?m=middle&f='.(int) $file->id.'&w='.$linkWidth.'&h='.$linkHeight.'"><i class="entypo-right"></i>JPG '.$linkWidth.' x '.$linkHeight.' px</a> </li>';
```

On the screen I am getting some thing like this:

```
https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.phpm=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276
```

All I am douing is selecting it on click.

Now I need to change this part so that my screen output is this  :

```
    {*<img src="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php
    m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276" 
    alt="" title="" width="390" height="276" vspace="20" hspace="20" border="0"
    style="width:390px;height:276px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;border:0px solid black;" class="" />*}
```

I've tried using ASCII for escaping inside of a `innerHTML`  , but as soon as I try to place `<img` my output start's breaking.

So just to add a bit more info :

1. It is not redirecting.
2. And all the functionality  I need is => select all on click, so that I can copy the output.

Is this possible?

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do? make a picture a link?

Comment: it needs to be a big "link" that on click someone can copy and use on a diferent page. it is not redirecting just sitting there. and copy on click

Comment: select all what on click? Are you using jquery - I did not see it tagged?

Comment: when user clicks. what do you want to happen? What are you trying to copy?

Comment: on click it is selectiong whole output so that user can copy it.

Comment: [This post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript) may similar to what you are trying to get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it to work. My question title was bad so I've change it.
All I needed to do is to change `innerHtml` and not `href`. Don't know what I was thinking.
This is my solution :

```
$downloadLinks .= '<li><a onclick="document.getElementById(\'last-crop-resize\').parentElement.style.backgroundColor=\'lightgreen\';document.getElementById(\'last-crop-resize\').innerHTML=\'{*<&#127;img src=&quot;\'+this.href+\'&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; title=&quot;&quot; width=&quot;'.$linkWidth.'&quot; height=&quot;'.$linkHeight.'&quot; vspace=&quot;20&quot; hspace=&quot;20&quot; border=&quot;0&quot; style=&quot;width:'.$linkWidth.';height:'.$linkHeight.';margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;border:0px solid black;&quot; class=&quot;&quot; &#47;>*}\'"; target="_blank" href="'._CONFIG_SITE_PROTOCOL . '://' . file::getFileDomainAndPath($file->id, $file->serverId, true) . '/' . PLUGIN_DIRECTORY_NAME.'/images/scripts/resize_image.php?m=middle&f='.(int) $file->id.'&w='.$linkWidth.'&h='.$linkHeight.'"><i class="entypo-right"></i>JPG '.$linkWidth.' x '.$linkHeight.' px </a> </li>';
```

The output is :

```
{*<img src="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php
m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276" 
alt="" title="" width="390" height="276" vspace="20" hspace="20" border="0"
style="width:390px;height:276px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;
margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;border:0px solid black;" class="" />*}
```

Thanks to everyone who tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear on what you're trying to achieve, but I think you are trying to use an image as a link?

If so here is what you need:

```
<a href="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php
        m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276">
    <img src="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php
    m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276" 
    alt="" title="" width="390" height="276" vspace="20" hspace="20" border="0"
    style="width:390px;height:276px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;border:0px solid black;" class="" />
</a>
```

Let me know if this helps

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but I think this is what you are looking for.

you are allowed to nest an `img` element in an `a` tag

```html
<a href="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php?m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276"> <img src="https://localhost/plugin/images/scripts/resize_image.php?m=middle&f=16788&w=390&h=276" 
    alt="" title="" width="390" height="276" vspace="20" hspace="20" border="0"
    style="width:390px;height:276px;margin-top:0px;margin-bottom:0px;
    margin-left:0px;margin-right:0px;border:0px solid black;" class="" /></a>
```

Comment: @BviLLe_Kid looks like you beat me to the same response.